# Facebook Android Tutorial logout

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, logout

I am following [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig). I got as far as to the point you retrieve the access token from the `savedPreferences` and then created a logout button. The problem is, it seems I access_token is always correct, no matter if I logout from my app or even from Facebook app.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();      

    Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook("whatever");
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    //UI elements
    private ImageButton fbLoginButton;
    private Button getInfoButton;
    private Button fbLogoutButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if(access_token != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Token found. Setting token " + access_token);
            mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if(expires != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setting expire " + expires);
            mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }


        if(!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
            mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"email", "read_friendlists" }, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", mFacebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", mFacebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Logging you in");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "Facebook error: " + error.getMessage() );

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User Canceled");
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Already logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        fbLoginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFBLogin);
        getInfoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGetInfo);
        fbLogoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

        fbLogoutButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doLogout();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void doLogout() {
        mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Logging you out");
              }

              @Override
              public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

              @Override
              public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {}

              @Override
              public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {}

              @Override
              public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I am always getting the `Already logged in` Toast.Am I doing something wrong?

PS. before retrieving the access_token from `sharedpreferences`, the app seemed to work fine, so it's not a problem with my API key or my debug key.

Comment: Try putting some log messages into the different functions inside `mAsyncRunner.logout` to see if you're getting some kind of error

Comment: @Kelmer have you solved this Issue or Not. Iam also Facing same issue Iam not Getting any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mFacebook.logout` and check reponse value. If logout is successful it will be "true". Works for me.

Don't forget about Single Sign-On feature. If you will be still logged in Facebook app it won't really logout you.

Comment: No but it will revoke the token hence it will be asked for again, won't it? Anyway, when signing out from Facebook app, it is still giving me the "already logged in" message

Comment: Maybe this is Toast.makeText(this, "Already logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); giving you this message? When yo do logout from Facebook it clears out all tokens so mFacebook.isSessionValid() return false after that, because your session is not valid anymore.

Comment: Exactly, as it should be returning false, no toast should be showing up since it's in the other path of the if statement.

Comment: Right, I am telling you that it returns this value since your sesion is not valid anymore and this is expected behavior after doing logout